# Bootstrap3 responsive broken

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

While i was editing my bootstrap3 page, i noticed responsive was broken.
I tried to figure out myself what i did wrong, but i couldn't find anything.
If anyone can give me an help looking at the code i would be grateful.

You can take a look at my jsfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/w07ugjyp/1/

```
   <div class="layout-container">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div id="navbar">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginModal">Join us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Downloads</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Rankings</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Vote</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Community</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.container-fluid -->
      </nav>

      <div class="container">
        <div class="layout-sidebar">
          <div class="side-control">
            <header><h2>Sidebar</h2></header>

            <div class="side-content">
              Content here
            </div><!--/.side-content -->
          </div><!--/.side-control -->
        </div><!--/.layout-sidebar -->

        <div class="col-md-9">
          Content here
        </div><!--/.col-md-9 -->
      </div><!--/.container -->
    </div><!--/.layout-container -->
```

Comment: what is the problem and what is the desired answer? don't say responsive, be more specific.

Comment: layout-container responsive is broken: it totally mess up when you switch page resolution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all your layout container has a min-width of 1000px.  That is why it will not become any smaller than that at mobile sizes.  Also you may want to think about not changing bootstraps css and making your own style sheet and loading it after bootstraps css.  It will make life a lot easier on yourself.  Example in your head tag:

```
<link href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="assets/css/YourCustomStyles.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Also bootsrap has a lot of the features you are trying to incorporate already built in like panels and things like that.  And also if you are trying to use bootstaps navbar you may want to incorporate the navbar-header and navbar-collapse or it will look kind of goofy.  If you are not going to use these things and dont want a dropdown menu then I suggest just creating your own list like the following:

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">Something</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Something</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Something</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Something</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

And give the `<li>` a `float: left;` and the `<a>` the css of `display: inline-block;` and go from there.  Otherwise at mobile widths your navbar-nav is going to display funny.  Personally I suggest just using bootstraps navbar components and dropdown.

Here is an example of what you are trying to do with using bootstraps components [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wamosjk/rogrb6xw/)

Anyway I hope this helps